# Is there a library that helps me create nice statistical charts for WPF?

Tags: wpf, statistics

I have to include some sort of reports for my university project and I already have the data ready to be used.

I'm thinking of using WPF for the GUI and I was wondering if there was a library or something I could use that has some nice effects for graphs and whatnot.

Any suggestions? I have to show information such as total shipments per area, which countries had the most shipments in a month, etc.

I'm thinking bar charts, pie charts and maybe some other things. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want these graphs to be part of the interface or as a report? If for reporting then maybe you could link your program with Excel.

Comment: As a standalone interface. No excel will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this:  [Practical WPF Charts and Graphics](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4570).  The link has sample codes you can download.  It might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Toolkit, which is free, has chart controls. You can download it here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535. These controls are of preview quality and most likely not all functionalities you want is included. It may contain bugs as well. However, the source code is fully downloadable and you can edit them as you see fit for your project. If you are looking for a more stable library with more features, I suggest you buy a commercial one.